# Unable to determine function entry point

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions

Been using MS botframework for a couple months.  Developing with the emulator in node and using continuous integration to push to Azure.

Pushed last Wednesday and tested with no problems.  Made two very inconsequential code changes and pushed on Friday and no I'm getting:

Exception while executing function: Functions.messages.  mscorlib: Unable to determine function entry point.   I tried redeploying the older version, same thing.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can I have your Bot Id to investigate this further?

Comment: Sure: xuba-sched

Comment: Matt, would you please either share index.js and function.json or email them to me at v-erdahl@microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was a short-lived bug in the Azure git integration and I deployed during the window this bug was live.  It modified function.json and left it in an invalid state.  Kudos to MS Support for staying with the issue and determining the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the root cause is having 1 named export & 1 default export.
To fix this, only export default 1 thing in the entrypoint file (index.js in my case)
Leaving here as a trail in case someone faces the same thing

Comment: Similar to this but mine was due to an exported variable. When I imported the variable in some other place like `import {theVariable} from ./FunctionName` this caused the confusion and it was seeing it as multiple entry points

Answer (score 2):

The function entrypoint is determined based on [this logic](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/azurefunctions/functions.js#L102-L128). As you can see, the flow is:

1. If an explicit entry point is defined in `function.json`, use that
2. Otherwise; if there's a single exported function, use that
3. Otherwise; try to use a function named `run` or `index` (in that order)

I suspect you were in branch #2, and your minor change introduced new functions, so the runtime is now attempting to locate a function named `run` or `index` and that doesn't exist.

Can you please make sure your primary entry point function is named `run` or `index` and try again?

Comment: Perfectly logical to suspect that.  However the only difference between what worked and what doesn't is I changed 2 console.log statements to session.send statements.  

And attempting to redeploy to the deploy that had worked 2 days prior or 2 weeks prior didn't fix it (well, the redeploys failed technically).  

Looking at the source for a new bot I created today from a template and index.js contains no functions called index or run.   Bot the bot works.  I'm confident no function in any code I've written was ever named run or index...?

Comment: This morning I redeployed one of the deployments from 4/26 which had worked fine.  Even though I got the same timeout on the redeploy, I let it continue to spin anyway and eventually got the check mark.  It currently says that version is running.  Still getting same entry point issue.  

Is there any way to get more detail (thinking stack trace) on what exactly is failing?

Comment: Host logs are available in the storage account setup for your Function App. You can also enable file logging to always write log files as documented here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json, just make sure you disable that once done as it will have a performance impact. 
About the entry point issue, do keep in mind that not having a run/index function doesn't mean it wouldn't have worked in the past, just makes the scenario described more plausible. If you don't mind putting the function code up on GitHub (even as a gist), I could take a quick look.

Comment: You have access to the code in my account, correct?  I really don't think it's a code issue as I have rolled back all the commits back to when it worked deployed previously.

As for the entry point, what is considered the entry point in a node bot written for the botframework?

Comment: Just for kicks I replaced the index.js of the bot with the basic echo template bot from MS.  Same entry point exception.  So I still don't think it's the bot code per se.   

Hopefully there's some way to determine what it's evaluating when it throws this exception.

Comment: Finally, I stopped the service, disconnected it from continuous integration.  Then went into debug console, removed all of my code and left the basic echo bot index.js in place.   Wiped all the node_modules and ran npm install again.  Brought it back up and STILL getting the entry point issue.  This is about as simplified as I can make the environment.  Need guidance.

Comment: Hey Matt, I'm sorry you're experiencing such difficulty.  Something strange is going on, to be sure.  I've been following this closely.  Someone should be contacting you on another channel shortly.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try stopping the service in Azure:

[image: Stop the Service]

2) Then go to `Kudu`: https://[YourAzureSiteName].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

and run `npm install`:

[image: npm install]

3) Then restart the service in Azure

Comment: Appreciate the response.  Unfortunately, this didn't work.  

I attempted to redeploy a build from 4/10 just for kicks and got a failure.  WebApiClient request timed out.  

I have no reason at this point to believe this is a code issue and every reason to believe something in my azure environment is corrupted.

Comment: WebApiClient?  is your bot written in node or c#?

Comment: Yes, I did not suspect this is a code issue.  There were some problems with deployments last month: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/19/Azure-Bot-Service-Issues-Resolved/

Comment: Also renamed node_modules and re-ran npm install and nothing has changed.  

"Unable to determine function entry point. If multiple functions are exported, you must indicate the entry point, either by naming it 'run' or 'index', or by naming it explicitly via the 'entryPoint' metadata property."

Comment: The bot is written in node.

Comment: It might be less complicated to re-create the service in azure, and redeploy your bot's code.

Comment: Another thing you can try (as a recovery option) is: go to Application Settings for your bot in portal.azure.com.  Look for the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING. Retrieve the AccountName value.  Then download the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer: http://storageexplorer.com/  The account name should be a StorageAccount that contains a File Shares node that has the source for your project.

Comment: Did that.  Same result.  I'll try it again with a completely new resource group.

Comment: Wow - created new service in completely new resource group.  Same behavior.   Same code works just fine with emulator.

Comment: I followed the Storage Explorer steps.  I see the File Shares but there's nothing underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `module.exports` for example:

```
module.exports = async function queryDatabase() {

    const pg = require('pg');
    //...
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are exporting multiple functions
for example function1, function2 then
by adding this line to the end of file we can resolve this issue.

```
exports.index = function1
```